# AngularJS: $watch

Tags: angularjs, pagination, scope, watch

I have this property : $scope.Users.length , according to it my app shows the pagination numbers. Although the property changes, the pagination not. I want to add $scope.$watch to take care of it, how do I do it ?

The pagination properties :

```
 $scope.totalItems = $scope.Users.length;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 3;
    $scope.maxSize = (($scope.Users.length / 3) + 1) ; //Number of pager buttons to show
```

the pagination in the html :

```
<div>
        <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-md" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" num-pages="numPages" ng-click="pageChanged(user)" items-per-page="itemsPerPage"></pagination>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way to do was to $watch the $scope.totalitems every time that a new data been add to the page.

the $watch function (put inside your add data function):

```
$scope.$watch('totalItems', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        $scope.pageChange($scope.Users.length);
    });
```

the function which will change the $scope.totalitems , which responsible for the amount of pages :

```
$scope.pageChange = function(pageNo) {
        $scope.totalItems = pageNo;
    };
```